# div layering not working properly : CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, html, layer

I am trying to make a semi-transparent background image for the entire page with the rest of the content layered over it (opaque). However, when I try to layer the divs, the pagecontent is semi-transparent as well. I've tried switching the z-indexes around and that doesn't change anything.

here are the two relevant styles

```
#backgroundImage
{
    background-image: url('/Images/background.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

#PageWrapper
{
    z-index: 2;
}
```

and here is the page markup

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Frontend.master.cs" Inherits="PTMS.MasterPages.Frontend" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="../Styles/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference runat="server" Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"/>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="backgroundImage">
        <div id="PageWrapper" >
            <div id="Header">
                <asp:SiteMapPath ID="MainMenuSiteMapPath" runat="server"></asp:SiteMapPath>
            </div>
            <div id="RightSide">
                <UserControls:Sidebar ID="RightSidebar" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div id="LeftSide">
                <UserControls:Navbar ID="LeftSidebar" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div id="MainContent">                
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpMainContent" runat="server">        
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>

            <div id="Footer">
                <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="Logged in as {0}" />
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    (<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />)
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you working w/?

Comment: If you use `opacity` all the child `div` elements will also be transparent.  You want use `rgba` instead.

Comment: I will look into that and get back to you - thanks for the tip :)

Comment: That solved the problem with the content being transparent, but now my background is not transparent. :/

Answer (score 0):

To make the **z-index** work you also need to have `position: absolute, relative, or fixed`.

So your `PageWrapper` style did not have any of this position value, so its not work.

Also the backgroundImage layer must be alone and the pageWrapper must not be inside him.

See the final results: http://jsfiddle.net/EnUaK/

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I moved the closing tag for the backgroundImage div so it was no longer wrapping the PageWrapper div, then set the opacity of the backgroundImage div and added position: absolute; to my PageWrapper.